# Unexpected result in YDKJS Closure section

Tags: javascript, closures

While studying Kyle Simpson's YDKJS Scope and Closure title, I came around the following example (2nd example) for a closure:

```
function foo() {
  var a = 2;

  function baz() {
    console.log( a ); //2
  }

  bar(baz);
}

function bar(fn) {
  fn(); //look ma, I just saw a closure
}
```

From my understanding, My console should output '2', though the output is empty
I'm using Chrome developers tools as the console. Any idea why my output isn't the value assigned to 'a'?

Comment: You need to call the `foo()` function.

Comment: Thanks, I wonder why it wasn't called in his example.